# Can I read from a query matching multiple documents Firestore Transaction in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read from a query and NOT from an individual document within a transaction.
My write is dependant on the result of the current data in the collection. But I seem to understand that, at least for the mobile and web clients, you are not allowed to read from queries, only from individual document reads.

If that's the case, how would I achieve that since I don't know what documents I want to read ahead of time?

Specifically, I'm referring to [this video from the Firebase team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOVSr0OsAoU&t=578s), at 9:38

Comment: If you want to transact on multiple documents from a single query, that can only be done in server-side code, not directly web and mobile apps.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you cannot read documents from a query inside a transaction, only individual documents.

So you would have to run the query with your conditions to determine the document IDs and then update the documents with individual updates, or with one or more batched writes instead of a transaction, if you need these writes to be atomic.

Here is a snippet that represents what I meant (in Javascript, not Flutter, but enough for a practical example):

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

const newDocumentBody = {
    message: 'hello world'
}

db.collection('myCollection').where('message', '==', 'hello').get().then(response => {
    let batch = db.batch();
    response.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const docRef = db.collection('myCollection').doc(doc.id);
        batch.update(docRef, newDocumentBody);
    })
    batch.commit().then(() => {
        console.log('updated all documents inside myCollection');
    })
})
```